# Lazy loading jsTree with Ajax - how to do it?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I am working on a  small file management system. It is used to replicate File system , so it shows both files and folders on the drive or folder you select.
Also, it uses jsTree ver 3 to display the system.  As there are millions of files/folders I would like to load each file/folder dynamically, one at a time.
This is what I have in my jsTree:

```
> function RedrawDirectories() {
>     $('#DestinationTree').jstree({
>         'core': {
>             "animation": 0,
>             "expand_selected_onload": false
>         },
> 
>         "json_data": {
>             "ajax": {
>                 "url": function (node) {
>                     return node.id === '#' ? 'Home/GetRootNode' : 'Home/GetSpecificNode?nodeId=' + node.id;
>                 },
>                 
>                 "type": "GET",
>                 "dataType": "json",
>                 "contentType": "application/json charset=utf-8"
>             }
>         },
```

etc.
So, in case I am at the root I call function that forms root link, and for any other node function GetSpecificNode with argument is called.

Here are my controlls at the backend:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetRootNode() 
{
    JsTreeModel rootNode = new JsTreeModel();
    rootNode.attr = new JsTreeAttribute();
    rootNode.attr.rel = "root";
    rootNode.data = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageDrive"];
    rootNode.attr.id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageDrive"];
    rootNode.state = "open root folder";

    return Json(rootNode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSpecificNode(string nodeId) 
    {
        JsTreeModel specificNode = new JsTreeModel();
        specificNode.attr = new JsTreeAttribute();
        specificNode.attr.rel = "folder";
        specificNode.state = "open folder";

        return Json(specificNode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Apparently, I need to add children for both root and specific node below.
I am using the following class structure to represent nodes at backend:

```
> using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
> using System.Web;
> 
> 
> public class JsTreeModel {
>     public string data;
>     public JsTreeAttribute attr;
>     public string state;
>     public List<JsTreeModel> children;
>      }
> 
> public class JsTreeAttribute {
>     public string id;
>     public string rel; }
```

The following **error** is shown in Firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:56357/Home/Home/GetSpecificNode?nodeId=undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide parameter name as follow

```
public JsonResult GetSpecificNode(string id) {
// Block of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetSpecificNode(string nodeId) 
    {
        JsTreeModel specificNode = new JsTreeModel();
        specificNode.attr = new JsTreeAttribute();
        specificNode.attr.rel = "folder";
        specificNode.state = "open folder";
        specificNode.attr.id = nodeid; //add this row

        return Json(specificNode, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Sorry to relive this topic, but for anyone who copied this code, the error was in the failure to set the attr.id of the node.